Are there human actions that cannot be (at least partially) explained or made intelligible?
While studying French mathematics education, I ran into the so-called anthropological theory of the didactic developed by Yves Chevallard. In it, he considers as the basic object of study the praxeology, which in his definition consists of two parts: praxis, which describes the practical part (and in the context of mathematics refers to 'tasks' and 'techniques' to solve them, i.e. ways of doing things), and logos, which describes a justification for the techniques which he calls 'technologies' and 'theories' (in mathematics that would be proofs and theories), which justify the technologies themselves. Further, he makes the following fundamental assumption: Any human action can be described by such a praxeology. To be more exact, his statement is the following:

[...] No human action can exist without being, at least partially, "explained", made "intelligible", "justified", "accounted for", in whatever style of "reasoning" such an explanation of justification may be cast.

My question is the following: Does the fundamental assumption that every human action can be explained by what he calls a praxeology hold true? In other word, is there a human action that we would not be able to explain in the terms he chose above? Ideally, I would like a few references on thinkers that have thought about these questions, so that I might form my own opinion, but a clear counterexample would work as well.

Brandom has a similar concept, the "game of giving and asking for reasons", which he describes as indispensable in maintaining human rationality in social practice. Is it possible for a human to fall completely out of this game? Sure, but that would mean losing their humanity. It is not an assumption, it is a condition on what it takes to stay human. Chevallard uses it as a methodological maxim of charity, human actions should be treated as reflecting humanity of the actors if at all possible.

Thomas Aquinas Emulator has something to say. An excerpt:  Aristotle states in Nicomachean Ethics that human action is always aimed at some good, and the practical reasoning leading to this good can be made intelligible. Further, in my Summa Theologica, I argue that human acts are voluntary and are always subject to rational analysis since they proceed from the will, which itself is an appetite for the good presented by reason.

Leonard Koan has a fascinating take on this question, claiming to see some cracks in the praxeology paradigm.
